# Recursively delete all files with a given extension

Tags: rm

I want to delete all `*.o` files in a directory and its sub-directories. However, I get an error:

```
sashoalm@aspire:~/.Workspace.OLD$ rm -r *.o
rm: cannot remove `*.o': No such file or directory
```

On the other hand, `rm *.o` works, but it's not recursive.

Comment: The "duplicate" is for removing *directories* matching a pattern, not files as in this question!

Comment: @Futal no it's not. The answer's title is a mismatch, but its accepted solution deletes files by glob pattern.

Comment: @roaima In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate, there is some discussion on whether the same solution means exact duplicate. I don't know which side is the "official" stance though.

Comment: A useful bit for find command - [“find: paths must precede expression:” How do I specify a recursive search that also finds files in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495501/465053)

Answer (score 465, accepted):

That is evil: `rm -r` is not for deleting files but for deleting directories. Luckily there are probably no directories matching `*.o`.

What you want is possible with `zsh` but not with `sh` or `bash` (new versions of bash can do this, but only if you enable the shell option `globstar` with `shopt -s globstar`). The globbing pattern is `**/*.o` but that would not be limited to files, too (maybe `zsh` has tricks for the exclusion of non-files, too).

But this is rather for `find`:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.o' -delete
```

or (as I am not sure whether `-delete` is POSIX)

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Can you please explain the curly braces and the plus sign in this context?

Comment: works fine on macOS

Comment: @AubreyRobertson See the man page for `find`. `-exec +` (in contrast to `-exec ;`) handles several files at once. The `{}` is the place holder for the file name / path (in both cases).

Comment: You should also add double quotes around {}, like: `find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm "{}" + `

Comment: @stpoa I encourage you to try to find an example where my code does not work as intended.

Comment: find has a delete flag. The things you learn each day. Excellent!

Comment: you can also use the fd utility instead of find to make the command a bit simpler: `fd --extension o --exec rm`

Answer (score 80):

That's not quite how the `-r` switch of `rm` works:

```
-r, -R, --recursive
          remove directories and their contents recursively
```

`rm` has no file searching functionality, its `-r` switch does not make it descend into local directories and identify files matching the pattern you give it. Instead, the pattern (`*.o`) is expanded by the shell and `rm` will descend into and remove any directories whose name matches that pattern. If you had a directory whose name ended in `.o`, then the command you tried would have deleted it, but it won't find `.o` files in subdirectories.

What you need to do is either use `find`:

```bsh
find . -name '*.o' -delete
```

or, for non-GNU `find`:

```bsh
find . -name '*.o' -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Alternatively, if you are using `bash` you can enable [`globstar`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option):

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
rm -r -- **/*.o
```

---

**NOTE**: all three options will delete directories whose name ends in `.o` as well, if that's not what you want, use one of these:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.o' -delete
find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm {} \;
rm -- **/*.o
```

Comment: When I run this with -exec rm -rf, it deletes a folder I'm trying to match & remove, then errors with `No such file or directory`, and exit code is non-zero... Is there a way to get around this error? (operation was still a success)

Comment: @SoylentGraham use `-depth` which makes `find` operate on the contents of a directory before the directory itself: `find . -depth -name '*.o'  -exec rm -rf {} \;`